# How to interract with all child widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to pull up a list of all the children of a widget? I want to take a frame full of widgets and interact with it, ideally like this:

```
for tile in app.children:
    tile["bg"] = "green"
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[winfo_children()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) is probably what you're looking for.